# How to update a Kafka file source connector when the file changes?

Tags: apache-kafka

So, though trial and error (brand new to kafka) I have managed to get an environment where when I run the file-source connector, it will push the contents of the file to a kafka topic.

However, when I update the file (a logfile in this case), the contents of the kafka topic don't update until I restart the file-source connector.

Is there a simple way I can have it update when the file updates?

Comment: I assume when you say updating the file, you are not appending new content. Is that correct?

Comment: Yeah I am appending to the log file, right now when I append to the log file manually, then manually restart the connector, the topic updates with the new log entries.